# Validation of the dynamic input field in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have a table where the row can be dynamically added and user able to submit the file for any row. I have a question here is how can I validate the file input?

[image]

I am using jquery to dynamically add / remove the row:

```
                            var row = 

                            "<tr> <input type='hidden' name='Registration_Tag[]'' value='" + Registration_Tag + "'>" +
                            "<td class='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap'>" +
                            "<div class='flex items-center'>"+
                            "<div class='ml-4'>"+
                            "<div class='text-sm font-medium text-gray-900'>"+
                            Equipment_Name+
                            "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "</td>"+
                            "<td class='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap'>"+
                            "<div class='text-sm text-gray-500'>"+
                            Registration_Tag+
                            "</div>"+
                            "</td>"+
                            "<td class='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap'>"+
                            "<span"+
                            "class='px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-green-100 text-green-800'>"+
                            Equipment_Status+
                            "</span>"+
                            "</td>"+
                            "<td class='py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500'>"+

                            "<div class='flex flex-wrap my-auto mb-6'>"+
                            "<div class='w-full px-3'>"+
                            "<input id='grid-password' type='file' placeholder='' name='Equipment_Cert[]'>"+
                            " <small class='text-danger'>{{ $errors->first('Equipment_Cert') }}</small>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "</td>"+
                            "<td class='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium'>"+
                            "<button type='button' class='remove-tr close'>"+
                            "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>"+
                            "</button>"+
                            "</td>"+
                            "</tr>"

                            $("#Calibration_Table").append(row);
```

I have tried dot notation like below but still no use for me.

```
                    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                        'Calibration_Location'=>'required',
                            'Calibration_Category'=>'required',
                            'Date_of_Calibration' => 'required',
                            'Next_Due_Date' => 'required',
                            'Equipment_Cert.*' => 'required'
                        ]);
                    if ($v->fails()) {
                        return redirect('/Equipments/create?request_type=Update+Calibration+for+All+Category')
                                    ->withErrors($v->errors())
                                    ->withInput();
                    }
```

Hope can receive some advice from you. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File upload inputs are handled a little differently in a Laravel request than other types of inputs. For example, a text input when empty will still be present in `$request->input()`. On the other hand, an empty file input is not set in `$request->input()` or `$request->file()`.

Your sample rule, `'Equipment_Cert.*' => 'required'` means "for every field in the `Equipment_Cert` array on this request, it should have a value". But because empty file inputs are stripped from the request, there is no `Equipment_Cert` array, so there are no elements in that array for this rule to be applied to.

If you want to make sure that there is a file element uploaded for every row in your dynamic form, you could do something like this:

```php
// I picked this field to count because it's a text input in your dynamic row
$dynamicRowCount = is_array($this->input('Registration_Tag')) ? count($this->input('Registration_Tag')) : 0;

$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'Calibration_Location'=>'required',
    'Calibration_Category'=>'required',
    'Date_of_Calibration' => 'required',
    'Next_Due_Date' => 'required',
    'Equipment_Cert' => [
        'required',
        'array',
        "size:$dynamicRowCount",
    ],
    
    // you can still do further validation on each file if necessary
    'Equipment_Cert.*' => [
        'file',
        'size:4096',
        'mimes:pdf,docx',
    ],
]);
```

With this rule, you'll get an error like `The equipment cert must contain 3 items` assuming there were 3 rows on the dynamic form. And if you wanted, you could further customize this message to something a little nicer, like `Each equipment row requires an uploaded certificate.`

Or, if you're able to change your HTML form structure, you could make each dynamic row in your form it's own array. Name your fields something like `equipment[][name]` and `equipment[][certificate]` and then your rules could be closer to what you originally tried:

```php
[
    'equipment.*.name' => 'required',
    'equipment.*.certificate' => 'required',
]
```

Comment: If you want to dig deeper on why empty file inputs aren't on the Laravel request, check out this article: https://joelclermont.com/post/2021-05/validating-file-upload-arrays-in-laravel/

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I will have a look on that!

Comment: Fields are going to be something like this:  equipment[0][name] equipment[0][certificate] ....